# how to deal with reused elements in selenium (duplication)

Tags: java, selenium

I am unable to locate element that is a button.

1st Button

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-6">
<input type="hidden" value="113" name="vendor_id"/>
<input id="vendor_submit" class="btn btn-primary mb10 SaveBtn" type="submit" value="Save & Close" name="submit"/>
```

I have used this command to locate it

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='vendor_submit']") ).click();
```

2nd Button

```
 <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-6">
<input type="hidden" value="113" name="vendor_id"/>
<input type="hidden" value="" name="vendor_hr_account_id"/>
<input id="vendor_submit" class="btn btn-primary mb10 SaveBtn" type="submit" value="Save" name="submit"/>
```

**Problem**

Now as they both are on same page i am unable to locate 2nd button due to duplication factor. Only the difference is type.
1st has value="Save & Close"
2nd has value="Save"

Please help me to locate 2nd button.

Comment: An id must be unique for a page. You should change your HTML so that each button has its own id. It's not a limitation of Selenium but a part of the HTML specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are two elements with the same id, I would suggest you try using `cssSelector` with its attribute `value` which would be unique for both and much faster than `xpath` as below :-

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#vendor_submit[value = 'Save']")).click();
```

**Edited1** :- If you are getting element is not visible exception when you're going to click, you should wait before click using `WebDriverWait` until element visible and clickable as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement submit = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input#vendor_submit[value = 'Save']")));
submit.click();
```

**Edited2** :- If unfortunately above does not work, try to click using `JavascriptExecutor` as below :-

```
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#vendor_submit[value = 'Save']"));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()",  el);
```

Comment: element not visible problem

Comment: So Is this visible on the page??

Comment: Try then using WebDriverWait to wait until it's visible and clickable..see edited answer and let me know.

Comment: 'WebElement html = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#vendor_submit[value = 'Save']"));
System.out.println(html.getAttribute("id"));'

Comment: above comment ... it is return main its id thats vendor_submit.. but then i used .click(). is says element not visible

Comment: Ok try to perform click using `JavascriptExecutor`, try with second edited answer and let me know...:)

Comment: there is no error but its not proforming click action

Comment: Did you tried to verify that locator is correct and locating correct element, if not go to browser console by pressing f12 at that page where element exists and execute this `document.querySelector("input#vendor_submit[value = 'Save']")` and let me know the result..

Comment: dont know exact syntax to execute that

Comment: Just copy exact this `document.querySelector("input#vendor_submit[value = 'Save']")` and paste into browser console and let me know it's returns correct element or not..

Comment: Or share `<form>` element Id if this submit button exists inside any `<form>`...:)

Comment: WebElement html = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#vendor_submit[value = 'Save']"));
System.out.println(html.getAttribute("id"));
     html.click();

Comment: dont know . what was problem when i was executing same command 1 hours ago.. for more then 10 times

Comment: Ok, now glad to hear you that finally it's working...:)

Answer (score 1):

You can differentiate by adding the value condition also in your xpath.
So basically you can use`.//*[@id='vendor_submit' and @value='Save']` instead in your `driver.findelement`

Comment: element not visible problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use only the `value` Attribute in `xpath`:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@value='Save']")).click();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use absolute xpath for both the button, as their positions are different in HTML.

For eg : `html/body/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]`

To get this add plugin firebug and firepath in mozilla and get absolute xpath from there by inspect element.

Comment: It's not recommended to use these kind of xpaths in Selenium tests. This may get the button you want now, but when you change 1 thing in your DOM, the test will fail, even if the button is still there.